# How to convert HDMI to VGA through a computer using software?

Tags: video

I have 1 monitor with VGA input only, 1 computer with only an HDMI output, and 1 computer with a VGA and HDMI socket.
I also have a VGA cable and HDMI cable. 
So my main question is:
**Could I use some sort of software to convert HDMI input from another computer into VGA output?**

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A more practical solution would be to install remote desktop software on each machine, then connect the two by Ethernet.  this would allow you to view the first machine's desktop from the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough this question does not seem to fit into this site, a possible answer is this: Computers with basic configurations (ones with only a standard graphics card or an on board gpu chip) by default do not have HDMI or VGA inputs but only outputs. So you need to use a capture card for the purpose of inputting any streaming HDMI video into your computer. Now if you have the mentioned input card installed in your computer system then you will probably be able to output (via its graphic card) the input as VGA into your VGA able monitor, at least in principle. You should look for practical realities for any successful application of this principle however.